# How to get multiple input lines in cli script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this simple node cli script.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const axios = require('axios');

( async () => {
    const lang = await inquirer.prompt([
        {
            type: 'list',
            name: 'to',
            message: 'Select translation language:',
            choices: ['it','en','es','fr','de','pt']
        }
    ]);

    const input = await inquirer.prompt([
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'from',
            message: 'Text to translate:'
        }
    ]);

    console.log(lang, input);

    const translation = await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single',
        params: {
            client: 'gtx',
            sl: 'auto',
            tl: lang.to,
            dt: 't',
            q: input.from
        }
    });

    console.log(translation.data);
})();
```

I want to create a simple cli translation tool but I have a problem with the user input. Since the program will run in cli, I need a way to give the user the ability to enter a multiline input text that can be translated. I've done a test with inquirer but using `editor` type for the prompt it will open a vim instance and it's not the best choice for non experienced users. Is there a way to give the user the ability to type multiple line input to process?

Comment: Try using readline, It gives you option to use line mode for CLI input

Comment: Can you provide an example?I have used in past readline but never used for multiple lines input

Answer (score 2):

Try using readline-

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rdLine = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rdLine.prompt();

rdLine.on('line', function (line) {
    console.log(line)
});
```

Comment: but if the user needs to insert a newline when enter is pressed this will process the input or I'm wrong?